# How do I set the size of my program's window? It seems to automatically be small. I'm using a lot of different 'containers' I guess

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, awt

With all the different 'containers' I'm using, it's hard to set my window size in the code. I guess I need them but at the same time need to find a way to change settings around it.

I've tried doing frame.setSize(int x, int y), did not work.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TweetProgram1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TweetProgram1();
    }

    public TweetProgram1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tweet Program");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TweetProgram1Pane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TweetProgram1Pane extends JPanel {

        public TweetProgram1Pane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Random tweet");
            JButton btn = new JButton("Send it");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = 300;
            gbc.gridheight = 300;
            add(lbl, gbc);
            add(btn, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

I expect to be able to re-scale the window size (in the code) to whatever I need it to be.

Thanks

Comment: *"How do I set the size of my program's window?"* Well `frame.pack();` will size the top level window to comfortably all the controls it contains, along with borders and padding etc, to the smallest it can be and still display them properly.

Comment: thanks. this makes sense